# Team Foundation Build 2013 environment variables

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, environment

I'm using TFS2013 with VS2013. I've read that TFS automatically stores values in environment variables as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx#env_vars

However, where do they get created? Is it supposed to be on the machine where Team Foundation Build service is installed? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Team Foundation Build Service will set the environment variables appropriately on the build agent server before invoking the build workflow.